# How many levels are in Necropolis?

Tags: necropolis

I've played down to level 6 and something tells me that's not a good number to end the levels at. The [Gamepedia's wiki](http://necropolis.gamepedia.com/Necropolis_Wiki) is very basic and doesn't provide much info.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Steam Necropolis Community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/384490/discussions/0/365172547957994750/) there are 10 levels BUT there are 308 listed in the game code.  People are stating that this is because the game progresses like another game - [The Binding of Issac](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/The_Binding_of_Isaac_Wiki) - where once you beat the game the first time you unlock more levels.

I hope this helps out!

Comment: could you link where the binding of isaac thing is mentioned?

Comment: Post #38 on the 3rd page of that forum [link](https://steamcommunity.com/app/384490/discussions/0/365172547957994750/?ctp=3)